# Guice injecting Generic type

Tags: java, generics, guice

I'am trying to Inject generic type with Guice. I have Repository< T > which is located in the Cursor class.

```
public class Cursor<T> {

    @Inject
    protected Repository<T> repository;
```

So when I create Cursor< User >, I also want the Guice to inject my repository to Repository< User >. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have UserRepository class ?

Comment: I do have one, but I have no idea how to inject it to generic, because there are some more repositories.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to use a [`TypeLiteral`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html):

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral;

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<Repository<User>>() {}).to(UserRepository.class);
  }
}
```

To get an instance of `Cursor<T>`, an `Injector` is required:

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.Key;
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    Cursor<User> instance = 
        injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Cursor<User>>() {}));
    System.err.println(instance.repository);
  }
}
```

More details [in the FAQ](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-to-inject-class-with-generic-type).

Comment: I thought the same, but did you try that out? I got `Repository<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified`.

Comment: I often use this kind of configuration without any problem. And i provide some links to the guice documentation

Comment: The thing is, I need the constructor to the UserRepository to be injected. So there's no way to call Guice.createInjector

Comment: The entry point of guice is the injector. How do you want to use guice without it ?

Comment: The difference between the examples in the guice documentation and the problem here is (guice documentation) `Collection<User>` vs. (here) `Collection<T>`. While the former can be injected, the latter gives the error message above. So did you try it out with something like `Collection<T>`?

Comment: @steffen In this case, @Gelidus needs to bind a `Repository<User>` to a `UserRepository`. There is no need to bind a `Repository<T>`. If you want to bind a `Collection<T>` to an `ArrayList<T>`, you could simply do `bind(Collection.class).to(ArrayList.class)`.

Comment: You're right, in my test scenario was a circular reference :-/

Comment: i know this is old, but i have what really feels like the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646780/dependency-injection-using-guice-with-the-dao-pattern and i'm struggling to figure it out. can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: What if I do not have an interface and implementation scenario? I just have one class, `Repository<T extends Foo>` and I need it to be injected in another class `Cursor<T extends Foo>`?

I have bind them both like this:
`bind(new TypeLiteral<Cursor<FooChild>>() {});`
`bind(new TypeLiteral<Repository<FooChild>>() {});`

But I still get the `cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.` error

Comment: new to guice, if I bind Repository<User> to Repository.class, then what would I do if I need to provide another type such as Repository<AnotherStuff>, what should I bind to ?

Comment: My generic type is comes from a package-private class and is therefore invisible to the module. Anyway to bind this?