# How to reflectively parameterise a generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, guice

How can I implement the following psuedocode in Scala using reflection?

I require this for the purposes of looking-up a generic type from Guice:

```
trait Foo[A]
class FooInt extends Foo[Int]
class FooString extends Foo[String]

bind(new TypeLiteral<Foo<Int>>() {}).to(FooInt.class);

def fooTypeLiteral(paramA: Class[_]): TypeLiteral[_] = ???

val foo = injector.getInstance(fooTypeLiteral(classOf[Int])
// foo: FooInt
```

Note: I **do not** have access to the type of `A` at compile time, hence the `_`. The entire solution needs to be performed reflectively (e.g. I cannot have `parameterizeFoo[A : ClassTag](...)`).

Comment: If you replace `???` by `classOf[Foo[_]]` and `===` by `==`, then it works as-is. It's just that the `classOf[Foo[_]]` does not know or care about the parameter passed to `Foo[_]` because of the runtime type erasure. If the type parameter is erased at runtime, and if you don't have it at compile time as some kind of type tag, then you have nothing to work with. Therefore, it's not clear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: I will be passing the `Class[_]` to `Guice.injector.getInstance(class)` so I'd assume the `class` instance would need to contain sufficient type information for Guice to perform the lookup?

Comment: No, `Class[_]` does not contain sufficient type information if the class has generic parameters. That's why [there are guice `TypeLiteral`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657127/guice-injecting-generic-type). Is it a duplicate?

Comment: Interesting. I would still need to reflectively generate an instance of `TypeLiteral<Foo<Int>>` as I don't know what `Int` is until runtime.

Comment: I think that it's a crucial enough detail that should definitely be added to the question then. The question should also be tagged `[guice]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a `ParameterizedType` and pass it to the factory method of the `TypeLiteral`:

```
def fooTypeLiteral(paramA: Class[_]): TypeLiteral[_] = {
  TypeLiteral.get(new java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType() {
    def getRawType = classOf[Foo[_]]
    def getOwnerType = null
    def getActualTypeArguments = Array(paramA)
  })
}
```

If you have only a finite number of `Foo` implementations, you could try this:

```
trait Foo[A]
class FooInt extends Foo[Int]
class FooString extends Foo[String]

val TLFI = new TypeLiteral[Foo[Int]](){}
val TLFS = new TypeLiteral[Foo[String]](){}

bind(TLFI).to(FooInt.class);
bind(TLFS).to(FooString.class);

def fooTypeLiteral(c: Class[_]): TypeLiteral[_] = {
  if (c == classOf[Int]) TLFI
  else if (c == classOf[String]) TLFS
  else throw new Error
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could comment which one of the two proposed solutions worked better.

Answer (score 0):

Both Scala and Java compilers implement generics with type erasure. This means that all type information for sub-types of generics is lost when the source code is converted to JVM byte code. If the generic class itself does not hold `ClassTag` or similar, embedded information, then you cannot get the class at run time.

Comment: Ok. And how then do guice's `TypeLiteral`s retain the complete type information?

Comment: Because you supply a fully qualified generic instance with bound types in the source code. The object you pass in to bind has all the necessary type information in place as it is constructed. What you are trying to do through reflection is quite different.