# How to inject generic type to non-generic interface type using Guice

Tags: guice

How do I inject generic type to instance of non-generic interface type?
for example:

I have interface class MessageHandler

```
public interface MessageHandler {
    public IMessage HandleMessage(String messagePath, String jobId);
}
```

I have generic class that implements this interface ProtobufMessageHandler

```
public class ProtobufMessageHandler<T> implements MessageHandler
{
private T message
}
```

I have an object that contains an instance of MessageHandler which should be filled with one of the implementations of the MessageHandler interface

```
public class Publisher {

private MessageHandler messageHandler;
}
```

I want to inject in some cases ProtobufMessageHandler into Publisher.messageHandler and in other cases inject ProtobufMessageHandler into Publisher.messageHandler

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think It is useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657127/guice-injecting-generic-type

Comment: Hello - could you please edit / clarify the last statement in your question? I think you have a typo, since it doesn't make sense :) *"I want to inject..."*